# How to force a page break in LyX?

Tags: lyx, page-breaking

Page break, New page, Clear page, Clear double page functions does not work for me in LyX. I tried to enter them via Insert ->.... and via LaTeX code `\pagebreak` etc.

But I desperately need to brake a page between two figures, because second picture occur inside the next subsection on the next page and that new subsection starts (in compiled PDF) right after the first figure. These two figures are too big to be placed at one page.

**EDIT:** [MWE can be downloaded here](https://content.wuala.com/contents/riabovvv/Documents/Public/MWE/MWE.zip/?dl=1&key=EEYAyx6Wz1iC)

**EDIT 2:** Here is the screenshot for MWE:
[image]

LyX version 2.0.6, OS openSUSE 12.3.

Comment: This sounds more like a figure placement than a page break issue. Could you add a MWE that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @vaettchen, what is MWE? May be you are right, but if I could break page there then there would be no problem placing figure right before next subsection.

Comment: Please, take a look at [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: and a LyX minimal example: http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: @vaettchen, MWE added

Comment: With your example I get the second section heading after the second figure. (I did have to change `babel` language and input encoding, but that shouldn't matter I think.) Try changing the float placement: right click the "title" of the inset (where it says e.g. *float: figure*), click Settings, uncheck *Use default placement*, select just *Top of page*.

Comment: @TorbjørnT, you could get right positioning if the first figure managed to appear at the first page instead of second. Is this the case? I added the screenshot of what I get. Placement at top doesn't affect final positioning (default placement is on top anyway).

Comment: Yes, the first figure ends up on page 1 (same as chapter heading), second figure on page 2, followed by section 1.2. However, I think that may be because I had A4 paper size, if I switch to US Letter I get the same output that you get. Edit: Concerning my last comment, I had misunderstood the issue a little, your screenshot cleared that up. You could set the *first* figure to be on a *Page of floats*.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., thanks you, seems that it works. Though results seems unstable for the main document, but due to last two compilations were successful, the issue seems to be solved. Consider posting your comment as an answer, so I could accept it.

Comment: If you go <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on a Mac) and then `\newpage` that should work. It does for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem of float placement, more than page breaking. One way around this specific issue seems to make the first figure be placed on a *float page*, i.e. a page containing only floats. To do that, go into the settings for the float by right-clicking on the inset "title" (circled in the below screenshot), and choosing Settings. Here, uncheck *Use default placement* and check *Page of floats*:

Again, for this specific case, it seems the first figure will fit on the first page if the paper size is set to A4, rather than US Letter. If A4 is what you really want to use, go to Document --> Settings --> Document Class, and add `a4paper` to the custom class options.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can add without any writing, just go to menu bar. As simple as that:
[image]

Comment: The OP mentioned they tried this and it didn't work for them...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the code you're inserting to force the pagebreak is getting lost w/ the figure calculations.

Instead, what you should do is erect a `\FloatBarrier` using the `placeins` package, I believe there's an option to prevent floats from appearing in a following section. There's some discussion of this in the TeX FAQ: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-floats

Comment: Thank you, it works. Unfortunately this methods brakes page right after the second figure, and I don't need this because it leaves a relatively small figure to occupy the whole page. BTW, I added MWE to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the following three worked for me:
1) Insert -> Formatting -> New Page
2) Insert -> Formatting -> Ligature Break
3) Insert -> Formatting -> New Page